# I get an Python BeautifulSoup None Type Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

```
url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
puan = soup.find_all("tr")
for i in puan:
    puan2 = i.find_all("td",{"class":"ratingColumn"})
    for x in puan2:
        puan3 = x.find("strong")
        print(puan3.text)
```

I'm scraping with BeautifulSoup. In the results I found, I get an error because there is NoneType in the list. How can I remove the NoneType parts from the list

Comment: When `find_all` returns None, that means it didn't find any of what you were looking for.  Specifically, there are no `<strong>` tags in some of your `puan2` set.  If you had added `print(x)` in your inner loop, you'd see that.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Adding a simple `if` guard will do the trick:

```py
if puan3 is not None:
    print(puan3.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I solved the problem because of you. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

Your selection is not that specific so you get a resultset, that also consists of elements you won't like to select.

#### How to fix?

Select your elements more specific:

```
i.find_all("td",{"class":"imdbRating"})
```

or

```
for row in soup.select('table.chart tbody tr'):
    rating = row.select_one('.imdbRating strong').text
    print(rating)
```

and additional with a double check:

```
for row in soup.select('table.chart tbody tr'):
    rating = rating.text if (rating := row.select_one('.imdbRating strong')) else None
    print(rating)
```

#### Example (based on your code)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

puan = soup.find_all("tr")
for i in puan:
    puan2 = i.find_all("td",{"class":"imdbRating"})
    for x in puan2:
        puan3 = x.find("strong")
        print(puan3.text)
```

#### Example (css selectors)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

for row in soup.select('table.chart tbody tr'):
    rating = rating.text if (rating := row.select_one('.imdbRating strong')) else None
    print(rating)
```